# SonataAdmin User's profile and avatar

Tags: symfony, profile, sonata-admin, avatar

I am using SonataAdminBundle. In the upper right corner there is a menu with a logout button and the user's avatar. 
What I can't find is how to access to user's profile to change among other things, the avatar and his password.

Someone can help me?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply go to your admins' user list e.g. http://example.com/admin/sonata/user/user/list

Edit the user e.g. http://example.com/admin/sonata/user/user/1/edit
and reset the **Plain Password**.

Since the **Avatar** is a new feature I don't think there is an upload feature yet.

Comment: I just checked the demo / sandbox and it doesn't feature anything yet too: http://demo.sonata-project.org/admin/sonata/user/user/1/edit (admin/admin)

Comment: that is correct when user has access to users's module, but when it hasn't ?
thanks in advance.

Comment: The (super)admin aka ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN in Sonata Admin has access to the complete user list. I think you are talking about a user and his profile where he can change e.g. the password? This is bases on a mix of the FOSUserBundle AND SonataUserBundle I think. Simply try /profile in your browser, does it show you anything? http://sonata-project.org/bundles/user/master/doc/reference/profile_edition.html

Comment: And this is how you can make it look: http://sonata-project.org/bundles/user/master/doc/reference/user_dashboard.html

Comment: I opened an issue to find out where the avatar functionality is going: https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataUserBundle/issues/529